# An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host

Tags: c#, sockets

Part of my C# windows Form is peer to peer (only two users) chat.
I use .Net Socket.

What I want to do is that whenever both users are available, they can chat. However, many issues comes up when one of them closes the program then opens it again. Or when only one is online I get this exception.

"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

I tried to use Socket.Close and Socket.ShutDown. I also tried to re-initiate the socket variable by defining it again. All seems not working. I am opened for any suggestion even using different libraries or methods.

The code is below:

```
namespace TextChatApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        //attributes:
        Socket sck;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            textBox1.Text=GetLocalIP();
            textBox3.Text = GetLocalIP();
            textBox2.Text = "8001";
            textBox4.Text = "8000";
            send.Enabled = false;
            connectEndPoint();
            InitTimer();
        }

        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
                if(size>0)
                {
                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
                    receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                    ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
                    listBox1.Items.Add("From a friend: "+receivedMessage);
                }
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Small Chat: " + exp.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void connectEndPoint()
        {
            try
            {
                epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
                sck.Bind(epLocal);

                epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox3.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));
                sck.Connect(epRemote);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
                start.Enabled = false;
                start.Text = "Connected";
                send.Enabled = true;
                textBox5.Focus();

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {

            }
        }

        private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
                msg = encoding.GetBytes(textBox5.Text);//

                sck.Send(msg);
                listBox1.Items.Add("You: " + textBox5.Text);
                textBox5.Clear();
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Small Chat: " + exp.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line(s) throw(s) the exception?

Comment: int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);

Comment: The thrown `SocketException` should have a `ErrorCode` property; does it correspond to one in the [Windows Sockets Error Codes list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2), and under your different scenarios do you get the same one each time?

Comment: Everything starts to get wrong after this exception. 0x80004005. it happens when one of the points sends data and the other is offline for any reason. I tried to make different methods to check if a point is online before sending data to avoid this condition. However, I did not solve it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my own issue.
Since I have the exception triggered when sending data and the endpoint is off or not connected, I should check if it is connected or not before sending the data.

However, there is no straight forward way to find if the endpoint is connected. 
Since when I send data and the endpoint is off it triggers exception, the exception became my indicator that the endpoint is off and connection is lost. So what I do is that I create the Socket again within the "Catch" statement and try again every period of time until the Socket is connected again.

The reason I create the Socket again every time exception triggered is because the Socket will be unstable and will lead to many connection issues. So better to create it again instead of having instability.

Here is the code I included

```
               private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
                {  
                 try
                {
                    int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
                    if(size>0)
                    {
                        byte[] receivedData = new byte[1500];
                        receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                        ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                        string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
                        listBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { 
                    listBox1.Items.Add("From a friend: " + receivedMessage); }));
                    }
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                    sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, 
                ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

                }
                catch(Exception exp)
                { /* here is the solution, when the Catch is triggered, close the 
                  socket and recreate it to avoid the issues that I been having of 
                  not sending messages and instability. I also added some functions 
                  that would keep sending the status and //being checked on the other 
                  side in order to keep online/offline status.*/

                    sck.Close();
                    sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 
                     ProtocolType.Udp);
                    sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, 
                     SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                    connectEndPoint();
                    //MessageBox.Show("Exception Small Chat: " + exp.ToString());
                }
    }
```